# How to mark a function with return type not to return?

Tags: objective-c, c, function, function-attributes

If I don't return anything in a function which returns something, compiler will warn about the function is not returning anything.

But If I call `abort()` in the function, compiler won't warn. How can I mark my own function like this.

Comment: If you don't want to return a value, make the method return `void`. If you do want to return a value in some cases, but not all, then pick a value that your return type can take which means "no value" or similar. You should never be deliberately omitting a return when the method requires one, this is bad practice and never really necessary in Objective-C.

Comment: @darvids0n This is usually required when calling utility function which does `@throw` internally.

Comment: You can use `[NSException raise]` to accomplish the same thing. Does the compiler still warn using this approach?

Comment: Compiler doesn't recognize `-raise:...` method so it still makes warning. And I want a small inline utility function (or method) which does some pre/post processing automatically by context.

Comment: If you wrap it in a `@try`/`@catch`[/`@finally`] block maybe that will get rid of the warning. Anyway, you seem pretty sold on using `__noreturn__` so I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__attribute__((__noreturn__))` should do it for Clang or GCC.  Since you've tagged your question for Objective-C, that should do it for you!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about standard :)

Answer (score 0):

I inspected the `abort()` function and discovered this attribute.

```
__attribute__((__noreturn__))
```

I think this is `gcc` specific extension, anyway this work well. If you know anything about standard stuff, please add another answer. Thanks :)

Comment: There is no standard way to have a non-returning function, since that concept doesn't exist in the language.